# 7 million files to load - any pitfalls?

Tags: mysql

I have been asked to bulk load 7 million CSV files into a table. So I wrote this script that I used for similar requests

```
cd /datafiles
for f in $(find /datafiles -type f); do
    echo $f
    mysql -h <myhost> -u <myuser> --password=<myuserpassword <mydb> -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${f}' INTO TABLE <mytable> ignore 1 lines"
done
```

I have used this script to load up to 31 files i.e one per day of the month. No  more than that.

The pipe-delimited CSVs (6 fields) are basically click data. In average, record count per file is around 50 records but it can go as high as 7000 and as small as 1.

The files are between 50 bytes and 800 Kbytes in size. My server has 64 GB of memory allocated.

Since the DBA is refusing to let me concatenate all the files into one merge file (something to do with db cache use), I don't have a choice.

Will I run into memory problems? My server is on Google Cloud. What are the possible pitfalls of doing something like this?

Comment: since we don't know how big your files actually are, or how much memory your server has allocated to it, it's a little difficult to say

Comment: 7 milion files. Are you sure?

Comment: @EdHeal Certain. I had a conference call 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @ADyson The files are between 50 bytes and 800 Kbytes in size. My server has 64 GB.

Comment: well I would _guess_ it will discard each file from memory as it's finished loading it, and then load the next one, so in that sense not having one massive file might be an advantage. But that's just my assumption, because it sounds like the logical thing to do. Unless anyone knows any better, maybe you can try with a handful (knowing the total size in advance) and see how much memory is consumed during the processing. Then you can extrapolate how much is likely to be used if you add more files into the batch.

Comment: IMHO the far more likely issue you'll face is just the amount of time it might take. You haven't mentioned whether you've got any constraints you need to work to in that respect.

Comment: If they are csv files with the same columns just concatenate them into one file

Comment: @EdHeal the question says "the DBA is refusing to let me concatenate all the files into one merge file"

Comment: I would question this rational

Comment: @EdHeal To my instincts that actually sounds sensible, one enormous file is potentially more problematic for memory and cache usage then a lot of small ones. But maybe you know better how the internals of mysql respond to that kind of thing? Perhaps it wouldn't actually load the whole file into memory all at once before processing it?

Comment: @ADyson There are no constraints to speak of.

Comment: 7gb file. It can just read the file without the need to start stop an connection. Besides it does not need the whole file in memory. One line at at time. No opening and closing files all the time.  Little os overhead in that department

Answer (score 1):

I would move file to a "done" folder when done.
And stop at any error.
Something like :

```
#!/bin/bash -e

cd datafiles
mkdir ../done

for f in $(find . -type f); do
    echo $f
    mysql -h <myhost> -u <myuser> --password=<myuserpassword <mydb> -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${f}' INTO TABLE <mytable> ignore 1 lines"
    mv $f ../done/
done

cd ..
```